# How to start webapp with embedded jetty from a different project

Tags: web-applications, jetty

here is a quick question: is it possible to start web-app with embedded jetty from a different project? 
I am trying to run (with JUnit) the following code:

```java
Server server = new Server(80);
WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
File webXml = new File("../Project1/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml");
context.setDescriptor(webXml.getAbsolutePath());
context.setResourceBase("../Project1/src/main/webapp");
context.setContextPath("/");
context.setParentLoaderPriority(false);
server.setHandler(context);
server.start();
```

If I do this from another Project, let's say Project2, jetty throws a lot of exceptions: 
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet

I've tried adding the Project1 to Project's 2 classpath, but this doesn't help the situation.
If I try to run the same come within the same Project1 (with all the paths adjusted, of course) - everything just works fine.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got the solution,

you either include your original webapp project as a dependency or use a custom classloader, if it's not possible:

```
WebAppClassLoader customLoader = new WebAppClassLoader(context);
customLoader.addClassPath("../Project1/target/webapp/WEB-INF/classes");
Resource jars = Resource.newResource("../Project1/target/webapp/WEB-INF/lib");
customLoader.addJars(jars);
webapp.setClassLoader(customLoader);
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to relative path strings.

Here's an alternative approach using JUnit Assert too...

```java
    Server server = new Server(80);
    WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
    File otherProject = new File("../Project1");
    Assert.assertTrue("Project1 should exist", otherProject.exists());

    // make path reference canonical (eliminate the relative path reference)
    otherProject = otherProject.getCanonicalFile();
    File webAppDir = new File(otherProject, "src/main/webapp");
    Assert.assertTrue("Webapp dir should exist", webAppDir.exists());
    File webXml = new File(webAppDir, "WEB-INF/web.xml");
    Assert.assertTrue("web.xml should exist", webXml.exists());

    context.setDescriptor(webXml.getAbsolutePath());
    context.setResourceBase(webAppDir.getAbsolutePath());
    context.setContextPath("/");
    context.setParentLoaderPriority(false);
    server.setHandler(context);
    server.start();
```

Or this could be due to the fact that `../Project1/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` does not have the dependencies you need.  This is important as the WebAppContext will use the provided `WEB-INF/lib` contents first, then the server classpath.

Comment: Still, the application misses all classes. All libs and classes are to be found in WEB-INF/lib if you are looking in a webapp under target folder. If I link webAppDir as target/webappname, then it starts. If it's a source that you want to start (src/main/webapp), all the classes and libs are linked to the project (which is different in this case). Any ideas here? Maybe extend servers classpath to project1?
Nevertheless, thank you for the help.